# In firestore security rule should we avoid error or is it the same as a deny

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my security rules I need to have certain property in some objects.

For example when a user post something it can only modified by himself so in the `/posts/` subcollection each post has at least the id of the owner.

Such as

```
{
   owner: 'idOwner-xxxxxx'
}
```

so in this example I set my security rules as such

```
service cloud.firestore 
{
  match /databases/{database}/documents 
  {
    match /posts/{postId} 
    {
      allow read;

      allow create: if request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;

      allow update: if request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
      && resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;

      allow delete: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

So simple a user have to upload a post with his own id and only has controll on it if his id is in it.

But on the simulator if I try to upload an object without the owner key exemple:

```
{
  notOwnerKey: 'qwertz'
}
```

instead of having a permission denied I get an error

```
Error: simulator.rules line [x], column [x]. Property owner is undefined on object.
```

I could avoid getting an error by checking for the key first like this:

```
service cloud.firestore 
{
  match /databases/{database}/documents 
  {
    match /posts/{postId} 
    {
      allow read;

      allow create: if "owner" in request.resource.data
      && request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;

      allow update: if "owner" in request.resource.data
      && request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
      && "owner" in resource.data
      && resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;

      allow delete: if "owner" in resource.data
      && resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

With this I get no error but the code is twice as long and will be a pain for nested object.

So here is my question.

Are there differences between errors and deny in permission in term of performance and good practice?

Should we avoid error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors are effectively the same as deny. You don't need to make your rules more complex to avoid them, you can just use them as an implicit deny.